# Meteor doesn't run jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

I have this jQuery code

```
if (Meteor.isClient){

jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    jQuery('#content .row > div').mouseenter( function(){
        jQuery('#content .row div .edit').toggle();
    });

    jQuery('#content .row > div').mouseleave( function(){
        jQuery('#content .row div .edit').toggle();
    });
});

}
```

When I run my app this just doesn't work. If I put that into chrome console it works perfectly. What's the problem?

This also happened before with different code.

Answer (score 4):

Your code adds callbacks to DOM elements that exist when your code is executed. However, Meteor will add stuff to the page later, when rendering templates. Here's how it should be done:

Option 1) Use Meteor events

```
Template.asdf.events({
    'click .classname': function(e) {
        ...
    }
});
```

Option 2) In the rare cases you need something that does not work in the previous way, put JQuery stuff in `rendered` callback:

```
Template.asdf.rendered = function(){
    _.each(this.findAll('.classname'), function(element){
         $(element).on('mouseenter', function(){...});
    });
};
```

Option 3) In the ultra-rare cases when you need some special treatment for all the page, use JQuery live binding

```
Meteor.startup(function(){
    $('#content .row > div').on('click', function(){...});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use meteor events.

For example use Meteor.startup(function () { instead of jQuery(document).ready(function(){

You must check up on http://docs.meteor.com/#eventmaps

may it be easy :)